# Pagination and concurrent update

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, pagination, h2

Lets suppose there is a table `products` with data

```
id | product | amount
---------------------
 1 | keyboard|   1
 2 | monitor |   2
 3 | computer|   3
 4 | mouse   |   4
```

And userA loads data from this table by two products. So he does
`SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY amount LIMIT 2 OFFSET 0` and he gets products with id `1` and `2`. However, while userA is reading two first positions  userB changed data in table, so it became

```
id | product | amount
---------------------
 1 | keyboard|   3
 2 | monitor |   1
 3 | computer|   3
 4 | mouse   |   1
```

Now UserA need the rest data so he does `SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY amount LIMIT 2 OFFSET 2` and he gets products with id `2` and `4` and this is not what he expected.

So we see here that there is a problem with pagination if there are more then one user and some user do updates while other are reading some pages. How are such problems solved? Of course in real example there are thousands of rows + joins.

Comment: In this case, one solution is to pass the whole data set to user a, and then handle pagination client-side.

Comment: Option A) Websocket listeners to watch for changes and update once a change is detected: Complex code.
Option B) Once a change is executed or a record is queries, always check the data before executing (done most, and often the use of ORM helps the developer in these scenarios)

Comment: @Norbert van Nobelen Thank you for your comment. Could you explain Option B? To tell the truth I don't understand what you mean there.

Comment: Option B) steps: 1) The user loads data, 2) The changes data (or clicks next), 3) the system checks if the data which the user is updating or loading has not been changed (ORMs help with this).

Answer (score 0):

In the above example, the order by variable is the challenge.

one way you can solve this is by,

- In the example, before binding next page query result data to the list, check whether any of the item in the result already fetched in previous query. if so, update those list item with its updated value and skip adding them again. This has to be done in the client side.

And it is always better to audit this kind of data by adding a field like "**LastModificationTime**" indicating when the row last modified, and display it along with other columns.